# BCC in automated mail

Tags: shell

I am trying to send automated mail to the users if the disk usage is above a threshold value for that i need some of the recipients in as bcc.

How can i achieve that using linux mail server?

And also i need to change the font style as bold in some mail content . please help me to sort out this issue.

```
if [ "$CURRENT" -gt "$THRESHOLD" ] ; then
mail -s 'HDFS Usage Eridu|| Housekeeping required   ' Jibin.Sebastian@abc.com,Surya.Inuganti@abc.com   << EOF
```

Mail body:

> THIS IS AN AUTOMATED MAIL PLEASE DON'T REPLY TO THIS MAIL.
>
> HDFS usage in Eridu Cluster is above the threshold please run the clean-up scripts asap. Used: $CURRENT%
>
> Current disk utilization report is
>   $DiskFile
>
> Please find the Utilisation report of top ten users consuming the cluster
>
> $Diskuse
>
> "THIS IS AN AUTOMATED MAIL PLEASE DON'T REPLY TO THIS MAIL."
>   i want the above sentence in bold and how add recipient in BCC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual page, `man mail` says on CentOS 7:

```
MAIL(1)                   BSD General Commands Manual                  MAIL(1)

NAME
     mail - send and receive mail

SYNOPSIS
     mail [-iInv] [-s subject] [-c cc-addr] [-b bcc-addr] to-addr...
          [-- sendmail-options...]
     mail [-iInNv] -f [name]
     mail [-iInNv] [-u user]
```

Looks like you are looking for the `-b bcc-addr` option.

There are no attributes like bold in text mail. Keep it simple, you don't want to send HTML mails.